# Not able to load Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

Am having a strange issue here. I have two templates in my app named app.
`base.html` and `view.html`. I have a button in my base.html page to navigate to my view.html. The problem am facing is when I am clicking the button in my base.html page the view.html page is not displaying(even though in the urls changed accordingly). Can some help me identify the problem? Thanks in advance.

My Folders and files:

[image]

And my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
def home(request):
    return render(request, "base.html", {})
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'app/view.html'
```

and urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from app.views import DetailView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^view/', DetailView.as_view(), name='view'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
```

and my button in base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{#<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>#}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Parasol.</title>
      <link href="{%  static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{%  static 'css/navbar-static-top.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{%  static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Parasol.</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photos <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Timeline</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Quotes<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Friends</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Heading Heading</h1>
        <p>
<a href="{% url 'view' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Let's go</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and view.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Chameleon Guys</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Its just for you dudes!!
    </body>
    </html>
```

### Edited

New directory as per Rekwan:

[image]

Comment: Show html code from both templates.

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks

Comment: try creating a directory named 'app' under templates folder. and move the `view.html` in `/templates/app/`.

Comment: I dont think that gonna work. Because I tried that already

Answer (score 0):

DetailView Render a "detail" view of an object.
that's [dev doc of cbv(class base view)](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)
Use template View and try

Comment: Hi Rakwen, I tried
my view.py as

`class GoView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'view.html'`
and urls.py
`url(r'^view/', GoView.as_view()),`
and my button in base.html as
`  <a href="{% url 'view' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Let's go </a>`
But am getting an error as 
`Reverse for 'view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: ok please post me your url.py and your current project directory organization !

Comment: don't forget view.py  please

Comment: Ok. Updated my question with new template directory. Thanks

Comment: my url.py
`from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, "app/base.html", {})

class TemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/view.html'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with the location of your templates. Templates should be found in `templates/appname/templates/view.html`. They should them be called by `templates/view.html`. In the snippets you have provided above you have `templates/appname/view.html`.

Furthermore, you have imported `DetailView` then proceeded to name your view `DetailView`. I think this overrides the imported class. Name your view to something other than the generics to avoid potential bugs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I've used the method as per Rakwen by using TemplateView. I've shared the updated codes above under his answer. Please help me there

Comment: Have you corrected the template path? That's the first obvious problem to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is as follows.Because now currently my home view looking for all kind of characters.

```
url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
```